# svn with ssh: authentication fails

Tags: ssh, svn, authentication

I am trying to update a remote subversion repository but if fails. 
Trying to debug it, this is the message:

```
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/balikas/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/balikas/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to scm.forge.imag.fr [129.88.34.5] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/balikas/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/balikas/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/balikas/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/balikas/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/balikas/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/balikas/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/balikas/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/balikas/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-5+b1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-5+b1 pat OpenSSH_5* compat 0x0c000000
debug1: Authenticating to scm.forge.imag.fr:22 as 'balikas'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64@openssh.com compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64@openssh.com compression: none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(2048<3072<8192) sent
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:F5s/dbFtkqwi2MPbvBufYRf4XLzyBit+D6Px8c97u4s
debug1: Host 'scm.forge.imag.fr' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/balikas/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I have renamed the ~/.ssh to ~/.ssh_backup and repeated the process, but it did not resolve. I also tried to force ssh ask for keyboard authentication by doing:

```
export SVN_SSH="ssh -v -o PubkeyAuthentication=no"
```

but still it does not ask for keyboard authentication.

So my questions (complementary):

1. How can I help the authentication problem?
2. Can I force for keyboard authentication, which would be a temp solution?

Comment: The server does not support password authentication. You can't force that from the client side.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot force the client to use an authentication method which the server *does not offer*. If it did, then the client would try to use it automatically after failing publickey.

In other words, the server administrators have disabled all other authentication mechanisms except `publickey`, so you must talk to them about why your key (the id_rsa file) was not allowed access.

The server-side settings for authentication live in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

Comment: The first time I tried to checkout the repository it asked for username/password though.  Once the user/pass were successfully put, then I didn't have to do it again. After upgrading to Ubuntu 16, it does not work anymore.